# rasterio mask method

Tags: python, shapely, rasterio

I am using a simple ASCII raster file to test the [`rasterio.mask` module](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html)

```
ncols 4
nrows 4
xllcorner 0
yllcorner 0
cellsize 0.5
nodata_value -9999
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I generated the following script which should extract all the diagonals

```
import rasterio
import shapely
from rasterio import mask

def extract_by_mask(raster_dataset, geometry):
    #outputs a numpy masked array with values within polygon geometry
    geometry = [shapely.geometry.mapping(geometry)]
    m = mask.mask(raster = raster_dataset, shapes = geometry)
    return m
r = rasterio.open('raster.asc')
p = shapely.geometry.Polygon([[0,0],[0.3,0.1],[1.58,1.5],[2,2],[1.56,1.8],[0.1,0.4]])
m = extract_by_mask(r, p)
print m
```

It does extract the diagonals, but I'm not comfortable with the resulting mask array:

```
(masked_array(
  data=[[[-9999, -9999, -9999, 4],
         [-9999, -9999, 7, -9999],
         [-9999, 10, -9999, -9999],
         [13, -9999, -9999, -9999]]],
  mask=[[[False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False]]],
  fill_value=-9999), Affine(0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, -0.5, 2.0))
```

It seems to consider that all the values are valid, such that when I take a mean it considers all the values including `nodata`:

```
>>> m[0].mean()
-7497.125
```

I have been playing around with some of the parameters in the `mask` method but no luck. I think the one I'm looking for in the [docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html) is `filled = False` but when I do this I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Basis/common.py", line 114, in <module>
    m = extract_by_mask(r, p)
  File "D:/Basis/common.py", line 109, in extract_by_mask
    m = mask.mask(raster = raster_dataset, shapes = geometry, filled = False)
TypeError: mask() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filled'
```

It doesn't seem to recognize `filled` as a valid argument. I am using `rasterio` version 0.36.0 by anaconda.

I need that mask array to show `True` for the diagonal values so I can only consider those for calculations.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I'd start by updating rasterio.   Current version looks to be 1.0.10 while you're on a pre-1.0 version meaning it was considered unstable (or at least that the APIs weren't finalized).

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly passing `nodata=9999` to `rasterio.mask.mask` may help output masked array with `True` at desired locations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `rioxarray`. An example of clipping/masking raster is [here](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html).

```py
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio('raster.asc')
geometries = [
    {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [[[0,0],[0.3,0.1],[1.58,1.5],[2,2],[1.56,1.8],[0.1,0.4]]]
    }
]
geometry_crs = "???"  # not sure what projection the geometries are in
rds_clipped = rds.rio.clip(geometries, geometry_crs, drop=False)
rds_clipped.rio.to_raster("clipped_raster.asc")
```